# executing stripe.exe in CMD?

Tags: php

I'm trying to test webhooks in localhost with stripe-cli as in the documentation in my local dev windows machine, I downloaded the .zip file and extracted the exe in Desktop, how can I execute it from cmd, I tried drag and  dropping into cmd tab but all I get is a list of stripe cli commands

Answer (score -1):

Try adding .exe to stripe for all commands. Like `stripe.exe login` or `.\stripe.exe login`